# Why doesn't my query work for retrieving substrings?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below is my query to show user comments. It works well:

```
enter 
$query='SELECT
customers.cust_id,
customers.f_name,
customers.l_name,
user_comments.comment_txt,
clubs.name_club
from
customers
    inner join
user_comments
    on customers.cust_id = user_comments.cust_id
    inner join
clubs
    on user_comments.cust_id = clubs.cust_id
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1,1
    ';

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$nameclub =$row['name_club'];
$comment =$row['comment_txt'];
echo '<div><img src="images/arrow.gif">&nbsp;<a   href="news.php?id='.$row['cust_id'].'">&nbsp;Name : '.$nameclub.'</a></div>';
echo '<div>'.$comment.'</div><br>';
echo '<div>'.$row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name'].'</div>';
}
echo '<p style="text-align: left"><a href="newsarchive.php">&nbsp;Show all comments</ ></a></p> '; ?>
```

I now want to show just about 100 characters of a user comment. So I changed my query accordingly, but it does not work:

```
enter $query='SELECT
customers.cust_id,
customers.f_name,
customers.l_name,
user_comments.comment_txt.substr(comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,
clubs.name_club
from
customers
    inner join
user_comments
    on customers.cust_id = user_comments.cust_id
    inner join
clubs
    on user_comments.cust_id = clubs.cust_id
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1,1
    ';

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$nameclub =$row['name_club'];
$comment =$row['comment_txt'];
 echo '<div><img src="images/arrow.gif">&nbsp;<a href="news.php?id='.$row['cust_id'].'">&nbsp;Name : '.$nameclub.'</a></div>';
 echo '<div>'.$comment.'</div><br>';
 echo '<div>'.$row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name'].'</div>';
 }
 echo '<p style="text-align: left"><a href="newsarchive.php">&nbsp;Show all comments</ ></a></p> ';   ?>
```

How can I fix my query to just get 100 characters of a comment?

Comment: `substr(user_comments.comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,`

Answer (score 5):

You're using [**`SUBSTR()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) incorrectly. Replace this:

```
user_comments.comment_txt.substr(comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,
```

With this:

```
SUBSTR(user_comments.comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,
```

---

**Edit per comment:** to add `...` if the text continues past 100 characters, use

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(user_comments.comment_txt,1,100), IF(LEN(user_comments.comment_txt) > 100, '...', '')) as comment_txt,
```

Comment: thanks all, how can i show continue of comment as "..." after show 100 character in my query ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Replace this

```
user_comments.comment_txt.substr(comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,
```

To

```
SUBSTRING(user_comments.comment_txt,1,100) as comment_txt,
```

[Mysql function_substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a php function that cuts a string into a number of words:

```
<?php

    function cut_string($string_to_cut, $number_words, $append = "...") {

        $string = array();
        $string_return = "";
        $return_string = "";

        $string = explode(" ", $string_to_cut);

        if(count($string) < $number_words) {

            for($x=0; $x < count($string); $x++) {
                $string_return .= $string[$x] . " ";
            }

            $return_string = substr($string_return, 0, -1);
        } 
        else {

            for($x=0; $x < $number_words; $x++) {
                $string_return .= $string[$x] . " ";
            }

            $string = substr($string_return, 0, -1);
            $return_string = $string . $append;
        }
        return($return_string);
    }
?>
```

Note: This is word count based, not character count based.